# Control Client Connection in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka here.

Is there a way that I can define/limit the client connections to Kafka broker?

If not, what is the default *[max connections possible and where is it set]*?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use quotas to limit resource usage

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas

And/Or you can enable security to authorize connections to the cluster

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_overview

In a production environment, I've seen hundreds to thousands of concurrent connections to a cluster. There probably is a theoretical limit to a single broker, but not sure what it'd be